# What's the "right" level for the surface of a concrete pad? At, above or below grade?

Tags: concrete, slab, ramp, pad, landing

Lots of information about how to lay a concrete pad, but nobody seems to address this overtly.

We're building a wheelchair ramp, the bottom is to be a concrete landing slab.  We are in the northeast US, so we get snow & ice (though the ramp likely would not be in use during the dead of winter - This is for a childrens summer camp).

I was going to build the wooden form such that the top of the slab rests around 1/2 - 1" above the surrounding grade.   The thinking being to basically keep water, mud, etc off it - "Self cleaning" of sorts

But I presented this to my partner, his thought was that it should be BELOW grade 1/2" or thereabouts.  This would protect it from being hammered by a potential snowplow incident (very valid concern) and he some other reasons which I'm unfortunately blanking on....

What say ye?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the most important feature of this slab is the transition to the ground level, which makes the slab fully wheelchair accessible. To avoid hitting by the snowplow, you can add a warning barrier, or make a strip of flower bed alongside the slab.

Place an adequate layer of coarse gravel, which shall be compacted to offer good bearing capacity, and deep enough to avoid damage by frost heave.

[image]

Comment: Neither above nor below because it's a ramp; dead on with the grade, +1. Having used an edging tool will keep it safe enough from a snowblower. Hit it with a plow; that's your fault. - That being said, for a *pad*, if it's not above grade and there's no sewer, then it's a pool....

Answer (score 1):

Above and with a slight slope so that it doesn't collect water.

Answer (score 0):

Or 1/2" below, with a slope and a drainage channel with gravel or similar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135921)

Comment: @FreeMan shame you did not make the same comment to the other answer - only difference is theat one said above.

Comment: @FreeMan This answer and my answer are equally valid in terms of SE rules - both answer the question, just happens to be both are one-liners.

Comment: Sorry, this answer was in the "Low Quality" review queue. @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact's answer was not.

Comment: Could you explain why this is a correct answer?  Beef it up a bit.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore has more words than another answer, why have you not picked on that one?

Comment: @SolarMike  Yours ended up in the review queue.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore then you should have spotted the earlier comments...